# Is this Banach fixpoint iteration proof correct?

Tags: analysis, numerical-methods

I'm preparing myself for an exam and don't have the solution to this task.Maybe you could look through it.

We are looking for the zero $x^*$ of $f(x)=\frac{1}{9}x^3-\frac{1}{3}x^2-\frac{1}{2}x+\frac{12}{9}$

a) Rewrite this problem in a fixpoint problem $\varphi(x)=x$. Than check the assumption for the banach fixpoint-theorem on $I=[1,2]$.

b) After how many fixpoint iterations is $|x_k-x^*|\le 10^{-3}$ if $x_0=2 ?$

My attempt looks like:

a) Let $f(x) := \varphi(x) - x \Rightarrow x_{n+1}=\varphi(x_n)=\frac{1}{9}x_n^3-\frac{1}{3}x_n^2+\frac{1}{2}x_n+\frac{12}{9}$

Check assumptions:
$\varphi(1)\approx 1,61 \gt 1 $  and  $\varphi(2)\approx1,88 \lt 2$ 
$\Rightarrow \varphi(I) \subset I$

$|\varphi'(x)|=| \frac{1}{3}x^2-\frac{2}{3}x+\frac{1}{2}| =\frac{1}{3}x^2-\frac{2}{3}x+\frac{1}{2} \le\varphi'(2) = \frac{1}{2} \lt 1 \forall x \in I $
$\Rightarrow \varphi$ is contraction
$\Rightarrow$ we can apply the banach fixpoint theorem

b) Let $x_0=2$ be the starting point and $1 \gt L \ge\frac{1}{2} $ with the a-priori estimatation $||x_n-x^*|| \le 10^{-3}$

$x_1= \varphi(x_0) = \frac{17}{9} $ than we have to calculate k such that

$$\frac{\frac{1}{2^k}}{1-\frac{1}{2}} |\frac{17}{9}-2| =\frac{2^{1-k}}{9} \le 10^{-3}  $$

$\Rightarrow k \approx 7.79 $

$\Rightarrow $ we need $k=8$ iteration

Edit:
Thank you so far.
Do I have to find the maximal value of $\varphi(x)$ on the intervall ?
If $\varphi$ were strictly monotone in-/decreasing than it would suffice to check the boundaries, yes ?

Comment: For a) you need to check that $\phi$ really maps $I$ into $I$ not only the boundary points. As for the Lipschitz constant, I don't how why you take $\frac{1}{6}$ as you have calculated the constant to be $\frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: @OlesWohnzimmer: I put x=1 instead of x=2 that's why I got $\frac{1}{6}$

Comment: You have calculated that $| \phi '(x)| \leq \frac{1}{2}$ for all $x$ in $I$. So you have to change that calculation to incorporate that. Otherwise, this looks fine.